# How to push my Records into SC.ArrayController content?

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views, sproutcore-controllers

I am trying to get my sample data (records created from fixtures) into my `SC.ListView`. I know the records are built properly because I am able to get particular data by finding it by its `primaryKey`.

The `SC.ListView` is pulling its content via `contentBinding: 'MyApp.thisController.arrangedObjects'` from this `SC.ArrayController`:

```
MyApp.thisController = SC.ArrayController.create(SC.SelectionSupport, {
    allowsMultipleSelection: NO,
    content: MyApp.store.find(MyApp.MyRecordType)
});
```

To init the store I use the function from the official guide:

`store: SC.Store.create().from(SC.Record.fixtures)`

How do I set my content property in the controller right to import the `SC.RecordArray`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that actually should work. When you do `MyApp.thisController.get('content')` what is returned?

Comment: as I said, the store is generated properly since I am able to access particular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will only work if your store is created before your controller.  Try doing

`MyApp.thisController.set('content', MyApp.store.find(....));`

after the app loads, in the console.  If that works, you need to query the store after  your app initializes.

Comment: You were right, the store was generated too late. Please see my answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that the store was generated AFTER the controller tried to set the content, which is very confusing because with the following code from another tutorial it is working fine.

```
store: SC.Store.create().from(SC.FixturesDataSource.create({
    simulateRemoteResponse: YES,
    latency: 250
}))
```

Anyone knows to tell me why the store creation in the question text fails to generate before?